# Add-On Installer On Mac does not install file at correct location and also does not detect previous installation of base installer

Tags: install4j

I have a MAC installer with media type single bundle. I need to create its Add-On installer. As on MAC Add-On installer support only folder type not single type so due to this I am facing two problem while installation : 1. It does not detect the installed main app automatically under installation location window unlike in case of windows platform where it does the same automatically. 2. It installs the files under the selected directory only but it should have install under /contents/java/app directory. Please advise on this how to resolve this.

Comment: As you said, the add-on installer only works with a folder installer, so you cannot use it with a main installer of type "single bundle".

Comment: But I need to have the add-on so what could be possible solution? changing the base installer to folder type?? For that I would need to do major change including the proposed design change. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to create a regular installer with the following properties:

A "Set a variable" action in the "Startup" node of the installer with a script similar to

```
ApplicationRegistry.ApplicationInfo[] applicationInfos =
    ApplicationRegistry.getApplicationInfoById("application ID of main installer");

if (applicationInfos.length == 0) {
  // The main application has not been installed before
    return null;
} else {
    File installationDir = applicationInfos[0].getInstallationDirectory();
     File targetDir = ...; // determine actual target dir in application bundle
    return targetDir;
}
```

- No files in the distribution tree
- No "Install files" action on the "Installation screen".
- A single ZIP file named "content.zip" added to the "Installer->Custom code & Resources" step, containing all files that should be installed
- An "Extract a ZIP file" action on the "Installation screen" with the "Zip file" property set to `${installer:sys.resourceDir}/content.zip` and the "Destination directory" property set to `${installer:targetDir}`

Comment: Thanks a lot Ingo! I will try implementing in the way you suggested.